# General synonym and part of speech processing using nltk

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I'm trying to create a general synonym identifier for the words in a sentence which are significant (i.e. not "a" or "the"), and I am using the natural language toolkit(nltk) in python for it. The problem I am having is that the synonym finder in nltk requires a part of speech argument in order to be linked to its synonyms. My attempted fix for this was to use the simplified part of speech tagger present in nltk, and then reduce the first letter in order to pass this argument into the synonym finder, however this is not working.

```
def synonyms(Sentence):
    Keywords = []
    Equivalence = WordNetLemmatizer()
    Stemmer = stem.SnowballStemmer('english')
    for word in Sentence:
        word = Equivalence.lemmatize(word)
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(Sentence.lower())
    text = nltk.Text(words)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    simplified_tags = [(word, simplify_wsj_tag(tag)) for word, tag in tags]
    for tag in simplified_tags:
        print tag
        grammar_letter = tag[1][0].lower()
        if grammar_letter != 'd':
            Call = tag[0].strip() + "." + grammar_letter.strip() + ".01"
            print Call
            Word_Set = wordnet.synset(Call)
            paths = Word_Set.lemma_names
            for path in paths:
                Keywords.append(Stemmer.stem(path))
    return Keywords
```

This is the code I am currently working from, and as you can see I am first lemmatizing the input to reduce the number of matches I will have in the long run (I plan on running this on tens of thousands of sentences), and in theory I would be stemming the word after this to further this effect and reduce the number of redundant words I generate, however this method almost invariably returns errors in the form of the one below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 45, in <module>
    synonyms('spray reddish attack force')
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 39, in synonyms
    Word_Set = wordnet.synset(Call)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1016, in synset
    raise WordNetError(message % (lemma, pos))
WordNetError: no lemma 'reddish' with part of speech 'n'
```

I don't have much control over the data this will be running over, and so simply cleaning my corpus is not really an option. Any ideas on how to solve this one?

I did some more research and I have a promising lead, but I'm still not sure how I could implement it. In the case of a not found, or incorrectly assigned word I would like to use a similarity metric(Leacock Chodorow, Wu-Palmer etc.) to link the word to the closest correctly categorized other keyword. Perhaps in conjunction with an edit distance measure, but again I haven't been able to find any kind of documentation on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently nltk allows for the retrieval of all synsets associated with a word. Granted, there are usually a number of them reflecting different word senses. In order to functionally find synonyms (or if two words are synonyms) you must attempt to match the closest synonym set possible, which is possible through any of the similarity metrics mentioned above. I crafted up some basic code to do this, as shown below, how to find if two words are synonyms:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
import itertools


def Synonym_Checker(word1, word2):
    """Checks if word1 and word2 and synonyms. Returns True if they are, otherwise False"""
    equivalence = WordNetLemmatizer()
    word1 = equivalence.lemmatize(word1)
    word2 = equivalence.lemmatize(word2)

    word1_synonyms = wordnet.synsets(word1)
    word2_synonyms = wordnet.synsets(word2)

    scores = [i.wup_similarity(j) for i, j in list(itertools.product(word1_synonyms, word2_synonyms))]
    max_index = scores.index(max(scores))
    best_match = (max_index/len(word1_synonyms), max_index % len(word1_synonyms)-1)

    word1_set = word1_synonyms[best_match[0]].lemma_names
    word2_set = word2_synonyms[best_match[1]].lemma_names
    match = False
    match = [match or word in word2_set for word in word1_set][0]

    return match

print Synonym_Checker("tomato", "Lycopersicon_esculentum")
```

I may try to implement progressively stronger stemming algorithms, but for the first few tests I did, this code actually worked for every word I could find. If anyone has ideas on how to improve this algorithm, or has anything to improve this answer in any way I would love to hear it.

Comment: I've been trying to get this code to work for awhile now, and it seems to be full of errors. For one, "worndet" isn't part of NLTK, and the package organization has moved around a bit.

Comment: Sorry, this code is 11 months old. Yes, nltk changed a bit, posted a changed and working version for the new version of nltk in place of the old one.

Comment: Also worth noting that wordnet lookups are actually quite slow and should in theory be delegated to a subprocess. If you'd like to clean this up a bit further and make it a better utility let me know and I can open up a gist for this on Github and copy you on it.

Comment: As a useful reflection on my programming improvements since then I rewrote a bunch of it to be faster and more pythonic and then also I made it pep8 compliant. Also the gist is here: https://gist.github.com/Slater-Victoroff/5713821

Answer (score 1):

Can you wrap your `Word_Set = wordnet.synset(Call)` with a `try:` and ignore the `WordNetError` exception? Looks like the error you have is that some words are not categorized correctly, but this exception would also occur for unrecognized words, so catching the exception just seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: To add to this: WordNet does not have every possible word, or every possible synset, so you simply cannot assume it will always return results.

Comment: WordNet might not have every word, but the conversion rate from words to synonyms is very low, even after lemmitization (less than 50%). I have included a try except, but there are deeper problems than the limits of WordNet. Also, none of the words I'm looking for are unusual or uncommon.

Comment: Are you sure that the words are being identified as the correct part of speech? [Reddish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reddish) is an Adj not a N, or do I misunderstand the exception message?

Comment: That's a part of it, and being able to solve that would be a great start on this problem. Do you have any idea as to how that would be possible?

Comment: Do you know if reddish is in the database? It could be that it says that unknown words must be nouns, but I am guessing...

Comment: Words not in the database actually do all get tagged as nn, but it also used for a lot of legitimate matches, and I'm not sure how I would figure out what the correct pos match was in an automated way.