# Find Python NLTK Wordnet Synsets for a each item of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nltk, wordnet

I've been learning basic python, but I am new to NLTK. I want to use nltk to extract hyponyms for a given list of words. It works fine when I enter every term manually, but it does not seem to work when I try to iterate through items of a list.

This works:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

syn_sets = wn.synsets("car")

for syn_set in syn_sets:
    print(syn_set, syn_set.lemma_names())
    print(syn_set.hyponyms())
```

But how do I get Wordnet methods to work with a list of items like

```
token = ["cat", "dog", "car"]
syn_sets = wn.synsets((*get each item from the list*))
```

in a loop?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I was going to answer this question but I do not understand what you are asking actually :D

Comment: The synsets accepts arguments of `synsets(lemma, pos=None, lang='en')`, so it just accepts 1 lemma, you need to iterate the lemma in a `for` loop, but what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Generally, I try to extract the complete list of hyponyms for every sense of the lemmas of a given list (like above)

Comment: After a little research, I tried                                                                                                          import nltk.corpus as corpus
wordnet = corpus.wordnet
list = ["cat", "dog", "car"]

for word in list:
    wordFromList = wordnet.synsets(word)[0]
    print(wordFromList, wordFromList.lemma_names(), wordFromList.hyponyms())

Comment: It does give the output I want, but only for the first sense of every noun...I could make a list in the style of "car.n.01", "car.n.02" etc., but WN does not seem to accept this input?

Comment: Now I do not understand, the `syn_sets` contains all the synsets, that is `car.n.01`, ...

Answer (score 6):

List comprehensions to the rescue!

Totally possible, even using very similar syntax to what you had before. Python has a construct known as a `[list comprehension][1]` made exactly for this application. Basically, it's a functional syntax for inline for loops, but tend to be cleaner, more robust implementations with slightly lower overhead.

Example:

```
tokens = ["cat", "dog", "car"]
syn_sets = [wn.synsets(token) for token in tokens]
```

This will even scale to slightly more complex data structures pretty easily, for instance:

```
split_syn_sets = [(syn_set.lemma_names(), syn_set.hyponyms()) for syn_set in syn_sets]
```

Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, but it should generalize to whatever you are looking to do similar to this.

If it's useful I asked a question about grabbing all related synsets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005529/general-synonym-and-part-of-speech-processing-using-nltk) a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have no choice but to loop through your words. I modified your code to have an outer loop, and it seems to work:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

tokens = ["cat", "dog", "car"]

for token in tokens:
    syn_sets = wn.synsets(token)
    for syn_set in syn_sets:
        print(syn_set, syn_set.lemma_names())
        print(syn_set.hyponyms())
```

Here is the output:

```
(Synset('cat.n.01'), [u'cat', u'true_cat'])
[Synset('domestic_cat.n.01'), Synset('wildcat.n.03')]
(Synset('guy.n.01'), [u'guy', u'cat', u'hombre', u'bozo'])
[Synset('sod.n.04')]
...
(Synset('cable_car.n.01'), [u'cable_car', u'car'])
[]
```

Comment: List comps yo. Python rarely requires outer loops.

Comment: Thanks, @SlaterTyranus, your answer was interesting, and probably more efficient. I still find mine more readable but, to put that in context, I get annoyed with Python for using colons and tabs instead of nice curly brackets ;-)

Comment: Noted, but code aesthetics are language dependent. For a more classical OO language(C++, Java, PHP, etc...) you would be totally right. Python (Guido) however has a strong belief in functional constructs. If you stick with it for a while you'll get used to it.